# Protractor tests , Jasmine and asynchronous solution

Tags: webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I using in my work protractor with jasmine . What found annoying and disturbing is ways I have to write always tests. I really don't like to do this waitsFor for promise from getCssValue. Can someone can show me better solution for asynchronous tests then this. At moment using Jasmine 2.0"

```
 describe('And I see a “Burger Menu” option on the  Header section', function () {
it('And the Left Hand Navigation is not visible When I access a Burger menu option on the ' +
'Header section Then I want to see the Left Hand Navigation menu', function () {
  runs(function () {
    Homepage.burger.click();
  });

  waits(500);

  runs(function () {
    Homepage.leftHandNav.getCssValue('display').then(function (item) {
      displayStatus = item;
    });
  });

  waitsFor(function () {
    return displayStatus;
  }, 200);

  runs(function () {
    expect(displayStatus).toBe('block');
  });
});
```

It seems like very complicated code for such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
expect(Homepage.leftHandNav.getCssValue('display')).toBe('block');
```

With the most recent versions it looks like working.

AFAIK expect waits internally for the related promises.