# Do protractor's expects wait internally for promises?

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, protractor

I came across this answer in a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118703/protractor-tests-jasmine-and-asynchronous-solution#):

'*AFAIK expect waits internally for the related promises.*'

Does anyone know if this is correct? I've searched the [protractor documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) for an answer with no luck. Can anyone point out the correct place in the documentation where it say this?

If it is correct, it would save me a lot of work! We have over two hundred tests, and to prevent timeouts I am converting all these types of calls:

```
expect(parentDialog.getAttribute('class')).toContain('k-window-maximized');
```

to this:

```
parentDialog.getAttribute('class').then(function(cls) { 
   expect(cls).toContain('k-window-maximized');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely true. `expect()` is "patched" by [`jasminewd`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd)/[`jasminewd2`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/tree/jasminewd2) (used by `protractor` internally) to implicitly resolve promises. Quote from the README:

> Enhances `expect` so that it automatically unwraps promises before
>   performing the assertion.

Here is an another documentation reference:

- [The WebDriver Control Flow > Protractor Adaptations](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#protractor-adaptations)

In other words, unless you need a real resolved value for further actions or calculations, you can safely pass a promise into `expect()`:

```
expect(parentDialog.getAttribute('class')).toContain('k-window-maximized');
```